# What the best Angular DataTables with custom options are for create enterprise application?

Tags: javascript, angular6

I have started using https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin this template, in future I have to use many tables but they are using ng2-smart-table in this template, am found many bugs and issues I have listed below for simple requirements.

1. Adding checkbox column (Tried adding but it simply disabled)
2. Not customizable options
3. Double Click on Row
4. Hidden column (To store id of record)
5. Binding html to table column
6. Grid not responsive on mobiles 
   and also login into to my project's dashboard takes very long time, I inspect the chrome's **Network** tab its downloaded 36.4 mb **resources** (what is resources in chrome developer tool ?).  is it heavy ?.

[image]

Is there any good data-table modules or libraries are available for creating enterprise level projects?

- Add , Edit, Remove options in table with validations and custom options to download format support PDF, Excel etc..
- Responsive
- Filter
- Pagination
- Sorting
- Dynamic Columns
- Row Expansion
- Scrolling
- Style

Comment: Another good option is ag-grid, which supports everything you mentioned. The community edition should work for the use cases you defined.

Comment: @Brian Ag-grid is fine but some features such as server-side pagination require a paid license. Deal-breaker for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [angular data tables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome),

Why Angular data table :
1-You have lots of resources on the internet related to it because it based on the jQuery data table (they covered lots of scenarios that you will need to display your data).

2-They have free Excel, CSV Copy, Print generator no need for a license.

3-lots of features such as
group by,
reformating the displayed data sorting the data footer, header, select by checkbox, hide columns

and lots of free features except add edit selected row if you want to use it you need a license for the editor.

**Update:**
I've used it with Angular 8 and it has all features that you've mentioned and more. but about Lazy loading, I'm not sure! you can check their website 90% of features that in the Jquery version you can apply it with Angular version.

If you understand how to use it with Jquery you can use it in easy with Angular.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but i couldn't see any options about this feature Excel, CSV Copy, Print . Can you send any example links having examples of Add , Edit, Remove options in table with validations and custom options to download format support PDF, Excel etc..

Comment: After implementing it as Angular you can use the features that included in Juqyer Data table you can check this link  https://datatables.net/examples/index

Comment: generate options check this https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: Add/Edit Form it's not free you can get it by licenses  https://editor.datatables.net/